# Relationship diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

So this is what I would like to have

Diagram 1
[image]

Diagram 2
[image]

Diagram 3
[image]

with help of [Nico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/28044/nico) i could draw it like that

```
  \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

% First diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, implies/.style={double,double equal sign distance,-implies}]

% LEFT PART
\node[draw] (weak_existenceleft) at (-8, 0) {weak\\existence};
\node[draw] (strong_existenceleft) at (-4, 0) {strong\\existence};

\draw[implies] (strong_existenceleft) -- (weak_existenceleft);

\node[draw] (uniqueness_lawleft) at (-8, -4) {uniqueness\\in law};
\node[draw] (pathwiseuniquenessleft) at (-4, -4) {pathwise\\uniqueness};

\draw[implies] (pathwiseuniquenessleft) -- (uniqueness_lawleft);

% RIGHT PART
\node(weak_existence) at (0,0) {weak\\existence};
\node(pathwise_uniqueness) at (4,-4) {pathwise\\uniqueness};
\node (strong_existence) [draw] at (4,0) {strong\\existence};
\node (uniqueness_law) [draw] at (0,-4) {uniqueness\\in law};

\draw (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north west) -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north east) % top
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=north east) %goes diagonally
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south east) % goes down
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south west) % bottom
      -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=south west) % goes diagonally
      -- cycle;

\draw[implies] (1,-2.4) -- (node cs:name=uniqueness_law, anchor=north);
\draw[implies] (2.9,-1.5) -- (node cs:name=strong_existence, anchor=south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Diagram 2 :

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

% First diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, implies/.style={double,double equal sign distance,-implies}]

\node(weak_existence) at (4,0) {weak\\existence};
\node(pathwise_uniqueness) at (0,-4) {pathwise\\uniqueness};
\node (strong_existence) [draw] at (0,0) {strong\\existence};
\node (uniqueness_law) [draw] at (4,-4) {uniqueness\\in law};

\draw (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north east) -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north west) % top
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=north west) %goes diagonally
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south west) % goes down
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south east) % bottom
      -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=south east) % goes diagonally
      -- cycle;

\draw[implies] (3.1,-2.2) -- (node cs:name=uniqueness_law, anchor=north);
\draw[implies] (1,-1.7) -- (node cs:name=strong_existence, anchor=south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Diagram 3

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

% First diagram

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, implies/.style={double,double equal sign distance,-implies}, rect/.style={draw, inner sep=1em},hexa/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum height=1cm, draw}]

\node[rect] (weak_existence) at (0, 0) {weak\\existence\\\\\\pathwise\\uniqueness};
\node[rect] (strong_existence) at (8, 0) {strong\\existence\\\\\\uniqueness\\in law};

\node[hexa] (best) at (4,0) {The best\\possible\\situation};

\draw[implies] (strong_existence) -- (best);
\draw[implies] (weak_existence) -- (best);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm still not entirely satisfied with this, could someone provide way to do it awesome
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

notice that for the first diagram the right draw doesn't looks great
could someone fix my draw  that's because of the size of the words i can't control them 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can start with this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

% First diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}]

\node(weak_existence) at (0,0) {weak\\existence};
\node(pathwise_uniqueness) at (4,-4) {pathwise\\uniqueness};
\node (strong_existence) [draw] at (4,0) {strong\\existence};
\node (uniqueness_law) [draw] at (0,-4) {uniqueness\\in law};

\draw (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north west) -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north east) % top
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=north east) %goes diagonally
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south east) % goes down
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south west) % bottom
      -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=south west) % goes diagonally
      -- cycle;

\draw[-latex] (1,-2.5) -- (node cs:name=uniqueness_law, anchor=north);
\draw[-latex] (3.2,-1.5) -- (node cs:name=strong_existence, anchor=south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation:

- Draw nodes. The `align=center` option is needed for the multiple lines.
- Draw polygon: start at the top left of weak existence, go to the top right, an so on.
- Draw arrows

The other part of the first diagram is easy:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, rect/.style={draw, inner sep=1em}]
\node[rect] (weak_existence) at (0, 0) {weak\\existence};
\node[rect] (strong_existence) at (4, 0) {strong\\existence};

\draw[latex-] (weak_existence) -- (strong_existence);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the last diagram:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

% First diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, rect/.style={draw, inner sep=1em},hexa/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum height=1cm, draw}]

\node[rect] (weak_existence) at (0, 0) {weak\\existence\\\\\\pathwise\\uniqueness};
\node[rect] (strong_existence) at (8, 0) {strong\\existence\\\\\\uniqueness\\in law};

\node[hexa] (best) at (4,0) {The best\\possible\\situation};

\draw[latex-] (best) -- (strong_existence);
\draw[latex-] (best) -- (weak_existence);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now it's up to you to glue all together =)

EDIT: You're being lazy...

I took the first code, copy and paste the second one and move it to the left. I had to change the node id because I've already used it in the right diagram.

I've also changed the arrow style

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

% First diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, implies/.style={double,double equal sign distance,-implies}]

% LEFT PART
\node[draw] (weak_existenceleft) at (-8, 0) {weak\\existence};
\node[draw] (strong_existenceleft) at (-4, 0) {strong\\existence};

\draw[implies] (strong_existenceleft) -- (weak_existenceleft);

\node[draw] (uniqueness_lawleft) at (-8, -4) {uniqueness\\in law};
\node[draw] (pathwiseuniquenessleft) at (-4, -4) {pathwise\\uniqueness};

\draw[implies] (pathwiseuniquenessleft) -- (uniqueness_lawleft);

% RIGHT PART
\node(weak_existence) at (0,0) {weak\\existence};
\node(pathwise_uniqueness) at (4,-4) {pathwise\\uniqueness};
\node (strong_existence) [draw] at (4,0) {strong\\existence};
\node (uniqueness_law) [draw] at (0,-4) {uniqueness\\in law};

\draw (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north west) -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north east) % top
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=north east) %goes diagonally
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south east) % goes down
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south west) % bottom
      -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=south west) % goes diagonally
      -- cycle;

\draw[implies] (1,-2.5) -- (node cs:name=uniqueness_law, anchor=north);
\draw[implies] (3.2,-1.5) -- (node cs:name=strong_existence, anchor=south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Nico Thanks for your trying  but as i said i'm quite noob i still can't make the first (with all the shapes ) and the second diagram

Comment: @Educ The second diagram it's almost exactly the same as the first one. Look a little bit, you just have to move some things around. Did you tried the code and tried to understand it?

Comment: @@Nico glue the things is the most difficult step i think even you can't do it, Thank you anyway

Comment: @Educ You are being lazy, it was pretty straightforward. Instead of the cheap "I think even you can't do it" you could have asked it gently or even tried to do it yourself and explain what problems have you encountered. I'm still a newbie, it's a lot of trial and error. Look at the edit.

Comment: @@Nico thanks i'm trying to make different arrows like original source

Comment: @Educ look at [section 15.3.5 of the pgf manual](http://ftp.inf.utfsm.cl/pub/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). That and a different end (instead of the `latex` end I used) should do the trick.

Comment: @Educ you can also use `implies`. Look at the edit.