# fixing diagram to be a good-looking diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

i draw this with help of question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160473/relationship-diagram)

notice that draw doesn't looks  good-looking diagram could someone fix it i think  that's because of the size of the words i can't control them to make it beautiful draw

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, implies/.style={double,double equal sign distance,-implies}]

\node(weak_existence) at (4,0) {Existence \\faible};
\node(pathwise_uniqueness) at (0,-4) {Unicité\\ Trajectorielle};
\node (strong_existence) [draw] at (0,0) {Existence \\forte};
\node (uniqueness_law) [draw] at (4,-4) {Unicité \\en Loi};

\draw (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north east) -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north west) % top
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=north west) %goes diagonally
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south west) % goes down
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south east) % bottom
      -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=south east) % goes diagonally
      -- cycle;

\draw[implies] (3.1,-2.2) -- (node cs:name=uniqueness_law, anchor=north);
\draw[implies] (1,-1.7) -- (node cs:name=strong_existence, anchor=south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{by theorem 1.2 }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
begin{figure}
% First diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, implies/.style={double,double equal sign distance,-implies}]

% LEFT PART
\node[draw] (weak_existenceleft) at (-8, 0) { \text{  Existence  } \\ faible};
\node[draw] (strong_existenceleft) at (-4, 0) {Existence\\forte};

\draw[implies] (strong_existenceleft) -- (weak_existenceleft);

\node[draw] (uniqueness_lawleft) at (-8, -4) {Unicité\\en Loi};
\node[draw] (pathwiseuniquenessleft) at (-4, -4) {Unicté\\trajectorielle};

\draw[implies] (pathwiseuniquenessleft) -- (uniqueness_lawleft);

% RIGHT PART
\node(weak_existence) at (0,0) {Existence\\faible};
\node(pathwise_uniqueness) at (4,-4) {Unicté\\trajectorielle};
\node (strong_existence) [draw] at (4,0) {Existence\\forte};
\node (uniqueness_law) [draw] at (0,-4) {Unicité\\en Loi};

\draw (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north west) -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=north east) % top
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=north east) %goes diagonally
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south east) % goes down
      -- (node cs:name=pathwise_uniqueness, anchor=south west) % bottom
      -- (node cs:name=weak_existence, anchor=south west) % goes diagonally
      -- cycle;

\draw[implies] (1,-2.4) -- (node cs:name=uniqueness_law, anchor=north);
\draw[implies] (2.9,-1.5) -- (node cs:name=strong_existence, anchor=south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{by theorem 1.1.}
\end{figure}
```

please could you please see my last request i've tried with it

```
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, implies/.style={double,double equal sign distance,-implies}, rect/.style={draw, inner sep=1em},hexa/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, shape aspect=0.5, minimum height=1cm, draw}]

\node[rect] (weak_existence) at (0, 0) {Existence\\faible\\\\\\Unicité\\trajectorielle};
\node[rect] (strong_existence) at (8, 0) {Existence\\forte\\\\\\Unicité\\en Loi};

\node[hexa] (best) at (4,0) {La meilleure\\situation\\possible};

\draw[implies] (best) -- (strong_existence);
\draw[implies] (best) -- (weak_existence);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{its me }
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option. I used `text width` and `minimum height` so nodes will have uniform size. I also used some auxiliary coordinates so that the arrows are placed automatically. Instead of defining a style for all nodes (which could produce undesired results, for example, in case `label` is used), I used a `mynode` style. I also changed to the shorter `<name>.<anchor>` syntax instead of `node cs:name=<name>, anchor=<anchor>`. Since the styles are going to be used in several diagrams, I made them globally accessible with `\tikzet` and not local to a given `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{caption}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={
  text width=2cm,
  align=center,
  minimum height=1.2cm
  }, 
implies/.style={
  double,
  double equal sign distance,
  -implies,
  shorten >= 3pt,
  shorten <= 3pt,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode] (weak_existence) at (4,0) {Existence \\ faible};
\node[mynode](pathwise_uniqueness) at (0,-4) {Unicité\\ Trajectorielle};
\node[mynode,draw] (strong_existence) at (0,0) {Existence \\forte};
\node[mynode,draw] (uniqueness_law) at (4,-4) {Unicité \\en Loi};

\draw (weak_existence.north east) -- (weak_existence.north west) % top
      -- coordinate[midway] (aux1) (pathwise_uniqueness.north west) %goes diagonally
      -- (pathwise_uniqueness.south west) % goes down
      -- (pathwise_uniqueness.south east) % bottom
      -- coordinate[midway] (aux2) (weak_existence.south east) % goes diagonally
      -- cycle;

\draw[implies] (aux2) -- (uniqueness_law.north);
\draw[implies] (aux1) -- (node cs:name=strong_existence, anchor=south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{by theorem 1.2 }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
% First diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}

% LEFT PART
\node[mynode,draw] (weak_existenceleft) at (-8, 0) { \text{  Existence  } \\ faible};
\node[mynode,draw] (strong_existenceleft) at (-4, 0) {Existence\\forte};

\draw[implies] (strong_existenceleft) -- (weak_existenceleft);

\node[mynode,draw] (uniqueness_lawleft) at (-8, -4) {Unicité\\en Loi};
\node[mynode,draw] (pathwiseuniquenessleft) at (-4, -4) {Unicté\\trajectorielle};

\draw[implies] (pathwiseuniquenessleft) -- (uniqueness_lawleft);

% RIGHT PART
\node[mynode](weak_existence) at (0,0) {Existence\\faible};
\node[mynode](pathwise_uniqueness) at (4,-4) {Unicté\\trajectorielle};
\node[mynode,draw] (strong_existence) at (4,0) {Existence\\forte};
\node[mynode,draw] (uniqueness_law) at (0,-4) {Unicité\\en Loi};

\draw (weak_existence.north west) -- (weak_existence.north east) % top
      -- coordinate[midway] (aux1) (pathwise_uniqueness.north east) %goes diagonally
      -- (pathwise_uniqueness.south east) % goes down
      -- (pathwise_uniqueness.south west) % bottom
      -- coordinate[midway] (aux2) (weak_existence.south west) % goes diagonally
      -- cycle;

\draw[implies] (aux1) -- (strong_existence.south);
\draw[implies] (aux2) -- (uniqueness_law.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{by theorem 1.1.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the third one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{caption}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={
  text width=2cm,
  align=center,
  minimum height=1.2cm
  }, 
implies/.style={
  double,
  double equal sign distance,
  -implies,
  shorten >= 3pt,
  shorten <= 3pt,
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
rect/.style={
  text width=2cm
  },
hexa/.style={
  regular polygon,
  regular polygon sides=6,
  shape aspect=0.5,
  %minimum height=1cm,
  draw
}
]

\node[mynode] (weak_existence) at (0,0) {Existence\\faible};
\node[mynode] (pathwise_uniqueness) at (0,-3) {Unicité\\trajectorielle};
\node[mynode] (strong_existence) at (8, 0) {Existence\\forte};
\node[mynode] (uniqueness_law) at (8, -3) {Unicité\\en Loi};

\foreach \Nodoi/\Nodoii in {weak_existence/pathwise_uniqueness,
  strong_existence/uniqueness_law}
{
\draw (\Nodoi.north west)
  -- (\Nodoi.north east)
  -- (\Nodoii.south east)
  -- (\Nodoii.south west) -- cycle;
}

\node[hexa,text width=2cm,align=center] (best) at (4,-1.5) {La meilleure\\situation\\possible};

\draw[implies] (best.east) -- (strong_existence.west|-best.east);
\draw[implies] (best.west) -- (weak_existence.east|-best.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{its me}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, you shouldn't be doing your cross-references by hand; you shoud use the `\label`, `\ref` mechanism.

Comment: @@Gonzalo Medina thanks you're always life saver

Comment: @@Gonzalo Medina could  you  please fix the second diagram i just add it to my question

Comment: @Educ same idea. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Educ please see my updated answer for the third diagram.